# Request-specific relationship() filtering (or alternative) in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy, pylons

I have a schema where most of the tables have associated users_*_meta tables which store per-user data like starred/unstarred, rating, and the like.

For example, `stories -< users_stories_meta >- users`.

However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to perform a joined load of a row and the related metadata row for the current user without either writing my own ORM on top of SQL Alchemy's expression builder or using a closure to generate a new session and schema for each request. (`relationship()` doesn't seem to support resolving components of `primaryjoin` lazily)

What would the simplest, least wheel-reinventing way be to treat the appropriate subset of the many-to-many relationship as a one-to-many relationship (one user, many stories/authors/elements/etc.) specific to each request?

Comment: Could you explain why don't you like SQLAlchemy's many-to-many relations? They work exactly as you want.

Comment: I want to efficiently load a list of all elements related to the currently logged-in user without having to either use `dynamic_loader` and sprinkle `.filter()` throughout my code or use `property()` and have to reinvent part of the ORM's collection abstraction every time I need to do this. (I want to keep the ability to modify the collection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a recipe at http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/UsageRecipes/GlobalFilter which illustrates how the criterion represented by a relationship() can be influenced at the per-query level.